# Constructor in one of the classes in deployer-web-extension-8.5.0 throws ClassCastException. Is there a patch available?

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, java, deployer

I was recompiling some of our custom deployer extensions (originally built for SDL 2013) with the SDL Content Delivery 8.5 jars, and one of the constructors of the class `ItemDeploySchemaManager` in `deployer-web-extension-8.5.0-1013.jar` attempts to cast a base class (BinaryStorageBase) to its derived class (BinaryStorage), which throws a ClassCastException since the base class is not an instance of this derived class.
This is the line of code causing the issue:

> this.binaryStorage = (BinaryStorage)data.getBinaryStorage();

Edit: pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.tridion</groupId>
    <artifactId>pageExtensionModule</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <tridion.version>8.5.0</tridion.version>
        <resources.folder>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</resources.folder>
        <extra.resources.folder>${project.basedir}/extra-resources</extra.resources.folder>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_core</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}-1011</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_model</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}-1013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_datalayer</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}-1014</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>deployer_web_ext</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}-1013</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tridion</groupId>
            <artifactId>cd_tcdl</artifactId>
            <version>${tridion.version}-1014</version>
        </dependency>           
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vs.ezlicrun</groupId>
            <artifactId>easylicense</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient-cache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludedGroups/>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to update your pom.xml file for more details?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain bit more detail what you are exactly trying to do with the deployer extension, It's difficult to help without source may you can add your class file which you have a problem?